# How to split a dataframe into multiple rows in python using a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I am trying to split a column into different rows using a delimiter(-).

| name | born | position | Points Per Game |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Curly Armstrong | 104 | G-F | 6.534653465 |
| Cliff Barker | 101 | G | 3.738255034 |
| Leo Barnhorst | 98 | F-G | 9.395348837 |
| Ed Bartels | 97 | F | 4.212765957 |
| Ralph Beard | 95 | G | 15.92063492 |
| Gene Berce | 96 | G-F | 3.333333333 |
| Charlie Black | 101 | F-C | 9.363636364 |
| Nelson Bobb | 98 | G | 4.634361233 |
| Jake Bornheimer | 95 | F-C | 4.233333333 |
| Vince Boryla | 95 | F | 11.18245614 |
| Don Boven | 97 | F-G | 8.450381679 |
| Harry Boykoff | 100 | C | 9.114649682 |
| Joe Bradley | 94 | G | 1.891304348 |
| Bob Brannum | 97 | F-C | 7.263313609 |
| Carl Braun | 95 | G-F | 13.36842105 |
| Frankie Brian | 99 | G | 12.28082192 |
| Price Brookfield | 102 | F-G | 4.857142857 |
| Bob Brown | 99 | F | 11.67741935 |
| Jim Browne | 92 | C | 1.516129032 |

I am trying to convert this into

| name | born | position | Points Per Game |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Curly Armstrong | 104 | G | 6.534653465 |
| Curly Armstrong | 104 | F | 6.534653465 |
| Cliff Barker | 101 | G | 3.738255034 |
| Leo Barnhorst | 98 | F | 9.395348837 |
| Leo Barnhorst | 98 | G | 9.395348837 |
| Ed Bartels | 97 | F | 4.212765957 |
| Ralph Beard | 95 | G | 15.92063492 |
| Gene Berce | 96 | G | 3.333333333 |
| Gene Berce | 96 | F | 3.333333333 |
| Charlie Black | 101 | F | 9.363636364 |
| Charlie Black | 101 | C | 9.363636364 |
| Nelson Bobb | 98 | G | 4.634361233 |

I need to do this so that I can find the F,C,G players who have the best points per position.
I tried this `finals_nba['position']=finals_nba['position'].str.split('-', expand=True)` but it did not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `finals_nba['position'] = finals_nba['position'].str.split('-')` then `finals_nba.explode('position')`

Answer (score 2):

```
df.assign(position = df['position'].str.split('-')).explode('position')
```

```
    name    born    position    Points Per Game
0   Curly Armstrong     104     G   6.534653
0   Curly Armstrong     104     F   6.534653
1   Cliff Barker    101     G   3.738255
2   Leo Barnhorst   98  F   9.395349
2   Leo Barnhorst   98  G   9.395349
3   Ed Bartels  97  F   4.212766
4   Ralph Beard     95  G   15.920635
5   Gene Berce  96  G   3.333333
5   Gene Berce  96  F   3.333333
6   Charlie Black   101     F   9.363636
6   Charlie Black   101     C   9.363636
7   Nelson Bobb     98  G   4.634361
8   Jake Bornheimer     95  F   4.233333
8   Jake Bornheimer     95  C   4.233333
9   Vince Boryla    95  F   11.182456
10  Don Boven   97  F   8.450382
10  Don Boven   97  G   8.450382
11  Harry Boykoff   100     C   9.114650
12  Joe Bradley     94  G   1.891304
13  Bob Brannum     97  F   7.263314
13  Bob Brannum     97  C   7.263314
14  Carl Braun  95  G   13.368421
14  Carl Braun  95  F   13.368421
15  Frankie Brian   99  G   12.280822
16  Price Brookfield    102     F   4.857143
16  Price Brookfield    102     G   4.857143
17  Bob Brown   99  F   11.677419
18  Jim Browne  92  C   1.516129
```